# Compactness of a set in a Locally compact Hausdorff space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

My question is about the following lemma:

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and $V$ be a nbhd. of a point $x \in X$. Then there is a nbhd. $U_{x}$ of $x$ such that $\overline{U_{x}}$ is a compact subset of $V$.

I'm following the proof of this(called Lemma 2.3 on page 5) of http://www.stanford.edu/class/math205a/radon-13.pdf.

In that proof, my question is: Why is $\overline{W}$ compact?

$\textbf{My work:}$
Suppose $\{Y_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \Gamma}$ is an open cover of $\overline{W}$. I want to use the compactness of $\overline{U_{0}}$ but can't seem to find a way to produce an open cover of $\overline{U_{0}}$ to operate on. Any suggestions or hints?

Thanks,

Vien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$W=U_0\cap V$, where $U_0$ is an open nbhd of $x$ such that $\operatorname{cl}U_0$ is compact. Thus, $W\subseteq U_0$, and therefore $\operatorname{cl}W\subseteq\operatorname{cl}U_0$. That means that $\operatorname{cl}W$ is a closed subset of the compact set $\operatorname{cl}U_0$. A closed subset of a compact set is always compact, so $\operatorname{cl}W$ is compact.

> **Lemma.** If $K$ is a compact subset of a space $X$, and $F$ is a closed subset of $K$, then $F$ is compact.

To prove the lemma, let $\mathscr{U}$ be any open cover of $F$. Then $\mathscr{U}\cup\{X\setminus F\}$ is an open cover of $K$, so it has a finite subcover $\mathscr{V}$, and $\mathscr{V}\cap\mathscr{U}$ is a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ covering $F$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a closed subset of a compact set. You also need the fact that compact sets are closed in Hausdorff spaces.